# Perl - Hash of Array: Key look-up by Value

Tags: perl, search, hash, grep

I have a hash of arrays (HoA). I have been processing the values of this HoA using `$arrayrefs`. However, now I need to retrieve the `$key` based on the `$arrayrefs`.

```
my %a =  ( 1 => "ONE" , 
           2 => "TWO" ,
           3 => " Three", );

my %aa =  ( 4 => [ 'ONE' , 'TWO', 'THREE'], 
            5 => ['one' , 'two', 'three'],
            6 => ['more', 'dos', 'some'],
);

my @array = ('ONE' , 'TWO', 'THREE');
my $array_ref = \@array;

# returns the $key where the $value is 'ONE'
my ($any_match) = grep { $a{$_} eq 'ONE' } keys %a;
print $any_match."\n"; # this returns '1', as expected.. Good!

my ($match) = grep { $aa{$_} eq @$array_ref } keys %aa;
print $match."\n";  # <--- error: says that match is uninitialized
```

In the last `print` statement, I would like it to return 4. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't compare arrays with `eq`. A simple solution is to turn both arrays into strings and comparing the strings using `eq`:

```
my ($match) = grep { join("", @{$aa{$_}}) eq join("", @$array_ref) } keys %aa;
```

For comparing arrays you could also utilize one of many modules from CPAN, e.g. [`Array::Compare`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Array%3a%3aCompare), [`List::Compare`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3A%3ACompare), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Always `use strict; use warnings;`.  Add `use v5.10;` since Perl's (v5.10+) smart matching will be used to compare arrays.  Do the following:

```
my ($match) = grep { @{$aa{$_}} ~~ @$array_ref } keys %aa;
```

The smart operator `~~` is used here to compare the arrays.